# Jetbrains rider: is there a way to start 2 projects in order?

Tags: jetbrains-rider

I've got a solution that has 2 projects. The first is a asp.net core 6.0 mvc app that calls a web service that is exposed by the second one (Web API alsso built with asp.net core 6.0). Is there a way for me to start both projects at the same time in order? I've tried the coumpound option, but it seems like there's no way for me to set the order (it will always be run in alphabetical order).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rider 2023.3, they added `Multi-Launch configuration﻿`, which allows you to start two or more projects in an order that you specify yourself. You can read about how to set it up on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/2023.3/Run_Debug_Multiple.html#multi_launch.

Here's a GIF from the documentation, which shows how to set it up:

[image: Gif image showing how to set up multi project launch in Rider]

And here's a copy of the text:

[image: Documentation of how to run multiple projects]